# Can I disable style chunking while using dynamic import with webpack4 in Vue project?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, import, webpack-4

I am using dynamic import and `webpackChunkName` in the router of my Vue project.
The imported modules use some Vuetify components.
Once I build the project I see some chunked CSS files which include duplicated content from the vendor CSS file.
How can I prevent this duplication?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I could have finally found out the solution myself.
I have changed `chunks` from `async` to `all` which enables sharing the chunks over all sync and async chunks.
This way no new chunks are created with the content from vendor CSS files.
Check [here](https://v4.webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/#splitchunkschunks) for more details.

Here's my WebPack configuration from my `vue.config.js`.

```
configureWebpack: {
    optimization: {
        splitChunks: {
            cacheGroups: {
                vendors: {
                    chunks: 'all',
                },
            }
        }
    },
}
```